# XSLT replace char with an element

Tags: xslt, replace

I'm trying to replace a single char with an element (containing more elements).
Using XSL 2.0.

Example:

```
<element1>
    <element2>some text and the char - I want to replace </element2>
    ...
</element1>
```

The - (dash) should now be replaced with a new element:

```
<element1>
    <element2>some text and the char <newElement/> I want to replace </element2>
    ...
</element1>
```

I tried already:

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="-">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <newElement/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
```

But this removed all the other elements inbetween (because only strings are "returned").

And with the function *replace()* you only can insert strings (no **<** possible).

Any further ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template matches an `element()`, but replaces `text()`. If you match `text()` and replace `text()` instead while copying the rest, it will work as expected:

```
<!-- modified identity template matching no text() nodes -->
<xsl:template match="element() | comment() | processing-instruction()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="-">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <newElement/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: matching angaist *text()* did it. Now the problem is, that this match isn't applied for the text of descendant nodes. It tried it with ```descendant-or-self::text()``` but no success. The problem is caused by another template match which renames an element and copies its text.... any ideas how to force the match all the time?

Comment: Because this is not part of the example, it is difficult to tell. I tested the XML `<element2>some text <elem3>I like - it!</elem3>and the char - I want to replace </element2>` and the output is as expected. The "modified identity template" excepts `text()` nodes as well. Maybe that does work for you as an inspiration. Otherwise I guess it would be best to create a new question with an example of what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Two corrections are needed:

- Your template should match `element2`, not `element1`.
- At the beginning and end of your tempate you should add
  opening / closing tag for `element2` (something like in
  the *identity template*).

So your template should look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="element2">
  <element2>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="-">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <newElement/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </element2>
 </xsl:template>
```

Of course, your script should include also the *identity template*.